# Cannot resolve “node:http” when using libp2p with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, libp2p

I am new to libp2p, so please excuse me if this is something that’s been asked/discussed elsewhere. I am trying to set up in a newly created project made with create-react-app. The app currently has one component with the following:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

import mplex from 'libp2p-mplex';
import Noise from 'libp2p-noise';
import Libp2p from 'libp2p';

class Connector extends Component {

```
constructor (props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
}

componentDidMount(){
    node = Libp2p.create({
        addresses:{
            isten: [
                '/dns4/wrtc-star1.par.dwebops.pub/tcp/443/wss/p2p-webrtc-star',
                '/dns4/wrtc-star2.sjc.dwebops.pub/tcp/443/wss/p2p-webrtc-star'
              ]
        },
        modules:{
            connEncryption:[Noise],
            streamMuxer:[mplex],
            transport:[WebSockets]
        }
    
    })
    console.log(node);
}

render(){
    return (<div>The connector component</div>);
}

}


export default Connector;
```

I know this alone is not enough to connect to anything, but it doesn’t even compile. I get the following error message when I run this:

Module not found: Can’t resolve ‘node:http’ in ‘/Users/myuser/projects/p2p-browser/node_modules/node-fetch/src’

I looked into the source code of the node-fetch module referenced and found that, indeed, it is requiring node:http. I also found that the node: prefix is to get node to include always node’s native http module. Since this is a react-app, which runs on the browser, I see no reason at all to use node-fetch, which leads me to think that either libp2p is not compatible with the browser, or somehow I am using the node.js version of libp2p instead of the “browser version”, though so far, I haven’t found any documentation to suggest there is a “browser version”, the examples I’ve seen use parcel and include the same npm modules. So, am I missing something, or is libp2p simply incompatible with create-react-app and needs to be compiled for the browser with parceljs?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.